# How to update firebase object of array on javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

{

"1101":["1234", 0],

"1102":["1102", 0]

}

This is my data.

How can I update data '1234' of '1101' to '5678' in javascript?

Answer (score 2):

The object has a syntax error. It should have a comma between the two objects `"1101" and "1102"`. You can change the object property this way:

```js
let data = {
  "1101":["1234", 0],
  "1102":["1102", 0]
}

data['1101'][0] = '5678';

console.log(data)
```

Comment: @perror Please accept the answer if it solved your problem. Thanks

Comment: my data is on firebase.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BUEX.png
then, How can I update that? This data is array.

Comment: Do you mean you want to update your data on firebase database?

Comment: Update firebase data on javascript.
(I'm not good at English...sorry...)

Comment: firebase.database().ref(schnum).update([change_pw1])


This is my code's part.
If I use this, my data's index 0 will update.


If schnum="1101", "1234" will be updated by this code.
But I don't know the reason.

Comment: You can update the data like that from the solution I have given and update firebase database with `firebase.database().ref(schnum).set(data)`

Comment: Don't you know why 
" firebase.database().ref(schnum).update([change_pw1]) " works well ?
If I use this code, only Index 0 will update. Index 1 never be updated and never be removed. I can't find the reason..

Comment: `.update()` updates the value you provide, keeping the other values in that object the same while `.set()` overrides the entire object.

Comment: then, what does  " .update[change_pw1] "  mean? How can It update only index 0? How can I update only index 1? and How can I add index 2 ?